# Title Attribute on Images Wrapped in an A tag in Safari, No workie?

Tags: html, safari, tooltip

I want to use the TITLE attribute to add a tool-tip to an icon button link. ("Edit this record" for instance.)  Like this...

```
<a href="edit.php"><img src="edit_icon.png" title="Edit Record" alt="Edit Record"></a>
```

This works in all browsers except Safari.  Safari shows the link URL instead.  Is this a new security feature?  I've googled around a bit and can't find anyone talking about it.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Put the TITLE attribute on the link instead.

(also, you should use an ALT attribute on the image)

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't work either. And you're right, I missed the ALT attribute, mea-culpa!

Comment: Man, thought it was a doctype issue but that didn't help either.  Here's a shot of the tip I see and the code behind the page.  WTF?  http://skitch.com/danberlyoung/rfyg8/title